# A custom one-page slider is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am working on an one-page site. The way you scroll/browse through the site is via a custom 'slider' that works by javascript. The problem is however, that the page doesnt slide as it should.

Sometimes when you load the page, it starts focussed in the middle of it. Aside from that, sometimes when you slide, the page doesnt slide at all, and sometimes it doesnt slide back (and so forth).

Preview URL: http://edu.serialshop.nl/ivproject/achtergrond.htm

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Skullcandy mediacollege</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: #3D3B3C;
}

.absolute{
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 75px;
    height: 233px;
    width: 255px;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
<script>
var pageSize = 1;
$(function(){
    $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
    $(".post").wrap("<td></td>"); 
    pageSize=$body.width();
    console.log($body.width());
});

function customScroll(amount)
{
    console.log("scrolleft: " + document.body.scrollLeft + " amount: " + amount);
    document.body.scrollLeft+=amount/10;
}
</script>
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.1-beta2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('resize',function() {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:window.location.href='#bottom'">
    <div id="map">
        <img src="images/achtergrond.jpg" width="3568" height="800" id="achtergrond" usemap="#m_achtergrond" alt="" />
        <img class="absolute" src="images/skelet.png" alt="skullcandy logo op een skateboard">
        <map name="m_achtergrond" id="m_achtergrond">
            <area shape="rect" coords="3142,0,3418,636" href="#" alt="Review" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="1957,0,2230,635" href="#" alt="Muziek" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="769,0,1039,636" href="#" alt="About us" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="-2,4,295,640" href="#" alt="Over skullcandy" />
        </map>
    </div>
    <div id="slider" style="position:fixed; margin-left:30%; margin-top:-10%;"></div>
    <script>
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'slider',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      var rectHeight = 50;
      var rectWidth = 200;
      var rectY = (stage.getHeight() - rectHeight) / 2;

      var hbox = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: -10,
        y: 70,
        fontSize: 24,
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        text: 'slider',
        fill: 'white',
        padding: 15,
        draggable: true,
        dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
            customScroll(pos.x);
          return {
            x: pos.x,
            y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
          }
        }
      });

      layer.add(hbox);
      stage.add(layer);

    </script>
    <span id="bottom">
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is $body.width()  replace it by $('body').innerWidth();

Comment: Wow, that page is causing my Chrome to griiiiiind. Why are you using canvas anyway? What you're doing could be done much easier with the DOM.

Comment: $body.width() is afaic a function of jQuery to return the body's width, aside from that its not used in the scrolling script.

Comment: @MattFletcher: could you please elaborate? By sending a link, a JSfiddle, or anything? Im not that well versed/good in jQuery/Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $body is not defined : /ivproject/achtergrond.htm:32
```

change `$body` to `$('body')` or add the line `var $body = $('body');` to your `$(document).ready(function(){});` block.

Comment: Ok, I changed that and it doesnt give the undefined error anymore. Nonetheless, my slider still bugs. THanks anyway